# How do I replace specific XElement objects with my own XElement object?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I'm working on a program that inserts pictures into a Microsoft Word document at specified locations in the document. For example, a page where the text reads "AUTOREPLACE 111", I would replace that with all of the images in a certain folder starting with 111.

I can do this with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, but this method takes a relatively long time to process. There are a few hundred images being added, and for each image added, I have to add crop values as well as manipulating a couple other variable in the image object. By relatively long time, I mean that this takes at least an hour to process the entire document.

I have been working the past few days on finding a faster way to do this, and have decided to Unzip the .docx file, add the images to the **media** folder, then manipulate the necessary .xml documents to replace the element containing the AUTOREPLACE text with the picture element.

Here is the xml for the AUTOREPLACE containing element:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00411330" w:rsidRDefault="00411330" w:rsidP="005C6ED0">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:tabs>
            <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="720"/>
            <w:tab w:val="left" w:pos="1260"/>
        </w:tabs>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:br w:type="page"/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:lastRenderedPageBreak/>
        <w:t>AUTOREPLACE 111</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Here is the xml for the w:p element that replaces the above xml

```
<w:p w:rsidR="0080275B" w:rsidRDefault="0080275B" w:rsidP="0080275B">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:jc w:val="center"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:noProof/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:lastRenderedPageBreak/>
        <w:drawing>
            <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
                <wp:extent cx="6031373" cy="8255000"/>
                <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="7620" b="0"/>
                <wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 1"/>
                <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                    <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
                </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                        <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                            <pic:nvPicPr>
                                <pic:cNvPr id="0" name=""/>
                                <pic:cNvPicPr/>
                            </pic:nvPicPr>
                            <pic:blipFill>
                                <a:blip r:embed="rId17" r:link="rId18"/>
                                <a:srcRect l="7516" t="4798" r="4248" b="1768"/>
                                <a:stretch>
                                    <a:fillRect/>
                                </a:stretch>
                            </pic:blipFill>
                            <pic:spPr>
                                <a:xfrm>
                                    <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                                    <a:ext cx="6031373" cy="8255000"/>
                                </a:xfrm>
                                <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                                    <a:avLst/>
                                </a:prstGeom>
                            </pic:spPr>
                        </pic:pic>
                    </a:graphicData>
                </a:graphic>
            </wp:inline>
        </w:drawing>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00411330">
        <w:br w:type="page"/>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

The method I am trying to set up now will iterate through the nodes of the XDocument loaded in until it gets to the node needing replaced, and replace it with an XElement object that I have created.

I am able to create the correct w:p XElement, but I'm having trouble with replacing the original element with my created one.

Here are the first 3 lines of the document.xml that is loaded in from the Unzipped Word document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
        <w:body>
```

The replaced **w:p** elements are child elements of **w:body**

Here is the test code I have so far:

```
XElement replaceElement = new XElement("replace");
ImagePageCreation iPage;

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
bool ReplaceFound = false;
XNamespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";

foreach (XElement xe in xdoc.Descendants(w + "p"))
{
    foreach (XElement xr in xe.Descendants(w + "r"))
    {
        foreach (XElement xt in xr.Descendants(w + "t"))
        {
            string innerText = xt.Value;
            if (innerText.Length > 10)
            {
                if (!ReplaceFound)
                {
                    if (innerText.Substring(0, 11) == "AUTOREPLACE")
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(innerText);
                        iPage = new ImagePageCreation("0080275B", "0080275B", "0080275B");
                        replaceElement = iPage.GetFullElement();
                        ReplaceFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (ReplaceFound)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ReplaceFound)
    {
        xe = replaceElement;
    }
}
```

I am unable to execute the xe = replaceElement because xe is a 'foreach iteration variable'.

What is the best way to identify the w:p element containing a w:r element containing a w:t element with a value AUTOREPLACE 111 and replace it with my own w:p element?

EDIT: I'm aware that the code example I posted would only work correctly on the first replacement. I want to get the replacement working, then I will get the looping logic corrected.

Comment: Would you be willing to use XSLT for this? Doing an XSLT transformation in C# is not a problem, and XSLT perfectly fits your problem. People here could write a suitable stylesheet for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`XNode.ReplaceWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.replacewith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to replace the original node with the replacement, for instance:

```
        var query = from xe in xdoc.Descendants(w + "p")
                    let replacement = xe
                        .Descendants(w + "r").Descendants(w + "t")
                        .Where(xt => xt.Value.StartsWith("AUTOREPLACE"))
                        .Select(xt => new ImagePageCreation("0080275B", "0080275B", "0080275B").GetFullElement())
                        .FirstOrDefault()
                    where replacement != null
                    select new { Original = xe, Replacement = replacement };
        foreach (var pair in query.ToList())
        {
            pair.Original.ReplaceWith(pair.Replacement);
        }
```

If you have multiple replacements, you could change that `.FirstOrDefault()` to a `.ToList()`:

```
        XNamespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
        var query = from xe in xdoc.Descendants(w + "p")
                    let replacement = xe
                        .Descendants(w + "r").Descendants(w + "t")
                        .Where(xt => xt.Value.StartsWith("AUTOREPLACE"))
                        .Select(xt => new ImagePageCreation("0080275B", "0080275B", "0080275B").GetFullElement())
                        .ToList()
                    where replacement.Count > 0
                    select new { Original = xe, ReplacementList = replacement };
        foreach (var pair in query.ToList())
        {
            pair.Original.ReplaceWith(pair.ReplacementList);
        }
```